# Powershell: Querying multiple strings and outputting to both user and file

Tags: powershell

I've been given the duty of validating installation of an update across many hosts. This validation is performed by querying for a string of an error code that signifies success. I would like this output to both appear in the shell and also be written to a file.

```
$computerList = @($userInput)
foreach ($_ in $computerList){
        get-content -tail 20 ("filepath") `
        | where {$_| select-string "All steps complete!"} `              
        | where {$_| select-string "Output Error = 0 "} `
        | out-file C:\users\me\Desktop\validation_log.txt -append                                               
        }
```

I based the multiple string "grep"-ing off of an online article, 
However, this doesn't write the desired strings to the out-file path, nor does it display in console.

Can anyone please explain the best method for querying multiple strings and then outputting those to a file?

Comment: Can't you combine the "where"s with -and or -or ?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is more complex than necessary.

You could just chain the `Select-String`. And `Tee-Object` is the way to go if you want to output something to both file and down the pipeline:

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Content -LiteralPath ".\input.txt"
All steps complete!
All steps complete! Output Error = 0
asdf

PS C:\temp> Get-Content -LiteralPath ".\input.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "All steps" | Select-String -Pattern "Output Error" | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString()} | Tee-Object -FilePath ".\output.txt" -Append
All steps complete! Output Error = 0

PS C:\temp> Get-Content -LiteralPath ".\output.txt"
All steps complete! Output Error = 0
```

The above behaves like an logical "and" for each pattern. If you want to "or" the patterns you could use the fact that the pattern is a regular expression:

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Content -LiteralPath ".\input.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "All steps|Output Error" | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString()} | Tee-Object -FilePath ".\output.txt" -Append
All steps complete!
All steps complete! Output Error = 0
```

Also notice that `Select-String` outputs `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` objects and not strings. You will probably get unwanted newlines in your output if you pipe these directly to `Tee-Object`. I therefore convert these to strings in the `Foreach-Object`

Comment: Hi there Paal, thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately, I am having trouble employing the advice you've given. I've done some testing with the code provided and what I'm noticing is that if I use:
`Get-Content -LiteralPath ".\input.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "All Steps"`
then the console will return the selected string. 

However, if use to consecutive Select-String statements (like in your example) 
`Select-String -Pattern "All steps" | Select-String -Pattern "Output Error"`

I observe that output is not generated. 
Version 5.1
https://www.screencast.com/t/deRQGHidt

Comment: @Udstrat You're experiencing the "or" vs "and" part I mentioned. In your screenshot you try to get the lines with both "Hello World" **and** "test2" in them. Your example input contains no such line and therefore won't produce any output.